# Creating Path With Double Backslash in Java

Tags: java, file-upload, path

So I retrieve a path from a local file and need to convert it to have a double backslash instead of the single one. However when I create a new file using the new path with the double backslash, it still reverts back to the single backslash and will give a FileNotFound exception. Am I doing this correctly? imgFile is a a file already created from the RequestParam and a JSP.

```
    String filePath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
    String fullPath = filePath.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    System.out.println(fullPath);


    File toUpload = new File (fullPath);
    System.out.println(toUpload.getAbsolutePath());
```

Output:

```
C:\\Users\\Joanne\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\eclipse\\seating_map_0204_635x613.jpg
C:\Users\Joanne\Desktop\Eclipse\eclipse\seating_map_0204_635x613.jpg
```

Comment: What's the output?

Comment: @shmosel added the println ouput

Comment: The second line looks fine to me. Why do you need the double backslashes?

Comment: I'm using Cloudinary to upload the image file. When I run Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(toUpload, ObjectUtils.emptyMap()); It gives the file not found exception

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with double backslashes

Comment: The double backslashes in the first output line look weird to me too. Joanne P, what makes ou think they might work?